# What's the minimum size of traces for the Press and Peel blue transfer paper?

Tags: pcb

I am thinking of using this method to create a two-layer board, but I'm afraid the traces I have to print are too thin to use this method without creating imperfections. Will I have problems with 0.25 mm traces?

Answer (score 1):

Press-n-Peel blue says it works < 5 mil (0.127 mm).  Personally I'd recommend doing some tests, as clearly a lot depends on how well you do it, as well as the spatial accuracy of your printer etc.

Looking at the example PCB from the manufacturer's website, an estimate of the track size is about 10 mil (0.254 mm).  (Pads appear to be 100 mil centres, about 10 pixels.)

[image]
https://www.fortex.co.uk/product/press-n-peel-pcb-transfer/

[image]
https://www.fortex.co.uk/download/press-n-peel-instructions/